# finding the greatest distance reached above the ground

Tags: kinematics

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCzf0.png)
[mark scheme answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7VPd.png)

I don't understand why there is an additional $0.441$ added to the final distance... I do understand that the distance travelled by $A$ downwards is equal to the distance moved by $B$ upwards but why the $0.441$? I solved it until the point where you find $s_1$ an multiply it by $2$ but afterwards it makes no sense.. can someone please explain

Comment: I will suggest to post this Q in another community: https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ hits the ground $B$ continues to move upwards. The string is now loose, so $B$ moves freely as a particle under gravity. The $0.441$ is the extra distance it moves until it comes to instantaneous rest.